# Failed To Generate DataConverter C++ Component

Tags: redhawksdr

I am trying to modify the DataConverter component from the REDHAWK repo on GitHub (https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/basic-components/tree/master/DataConverter) to convert data from float to the complex float data type, so I send data can send data to be transmitted by the USRP (which only accepts complex float as an input).

However, after I added the new ports and properties for the complex float data type I went to generate the component and received the error

```
GENERATE FAILED: Failed to find implementation settings for implementation DCE:f744f32f-510a-4e64-9124-3507d5568e39
```

When I look at the Implementations tab of the DataConverter.spd.xml I noticed the section named "Code Generation Details" is missing. The content of DataConvert.spd.xml is below. For reference, I'm running REDHAWK 1.9 on Centos 6.4 x64.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- 
          This file is protected by Copyright. Please refer to the COPYRIGHT file distributed with this 
               source distribution.

This file is part of REDHAWK Basic Components DataConverter.

REDHAWK Basic Components DataConverter is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of 
the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either 
version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

REDHAWK Basic Components DataConverter is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; 
without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR 
PURPOSE.  See the GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License along with this 
program.  If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
-->
<!DOCTYPE softpkg PUBLIC "-//JTRS//DTD SCA V2.2.2 SPD//EN" "softpkg.dtd">
<softpkg id="DCE:892a34ce-22c9-4719-b823-9f2e199aa69c" name="DataConverter" type="sca_compliant">
  <title></title>
  <author>
    <name></name>
  </author>
  <propertyfile type="PRF">
    <localfile name="DataConverter.prf.xml"/>
  </propertyfile>
  <descriptor>
    <localfile name="DataConverter.scd.xml"/>
  </descriptor>
  <implementation id="DCE:f744f32f-510a-4e64-9124-3507d5568e39">
    <description>The implementation contains descriptive information about the template for a software component.</description>
    <code type="Executable">
      <localfile name="DataConverter/DataConverter"/>
      <entrypoint>DataConverter/DataConverter</entrypoint>
    </code>
    <compiler name="/usr/bin/gcc" version="4.1.2"/>
    <programminglanguage name="C++"/>
    <humanlanguage name="EN"/>
    <os name="Linux"/>
    <processor name="x86"/>
    <processor name="x86_64"/>
  </implementation>
</softpkg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a required hidden file from the project has been removed, specifically ".DataConverter.wavedev".  The file which ties the component's implementation to a specific code generator is called the wavedev file.  For more information on the hidden files used by the Eclipse IDE see [Chapter 20.1.1](http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch20.html) in the v1.9 REDHAWK documentation.

If you cloned this project from the git repository you should be able to confirm this using git status.  If this is the case, you can use git commands to re-checkout this missing file.  From the root of the basic-components repository:

`git checkout DataConverter/.DataConverter.wavedev`

The wavedev file for this project may also be viewed [here](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/basic-components/blob/develop-1.9/DataConverter/.DataConverter.wavedev)